# Reshaping a messy dataset using Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reshape

I got this messy dataset from a csv-file that contains multiple entries in the same cell.
This is how it looks:

```
file = ('messy.csv')
df = pd.read_csv(file)

df.head()


Folders            Files
                                          
aa; bb;            aa.src aa.xml ; bb.src bb.war ;
cc;                cc.pom cc.py cc.js ;
dd; ee; ff;        dd.ts dd.js ; ee.py ; ff.xml ff.js ;
```

In the Folders column the values are separated with a semicolon ";". In the Files column the values are separated with a space and a semicolon " ;". Files that belongs to the same Folder are only separated with a space. I need help to reshape this into a more manageable dataframe, or into a JSON-dict/list. I haven't found many examples in which there are multiple values in the same cell that I can take help from.

Sure, a "manageable" format is kinda ambiguous but anything is better than this...

Something like this maybe:

```
Folders            Files 1   Files 2   Files 3
                                          
aa                 aa.src    aa.xml    NaN
bb                 bb.src    bb.war    NaN
cc                 cc.pom    cc.py     cc.js
dd                 dd.ts     dd.js     NaN
ee                 ee.py     NaN       NaN
ff                 ff.xml    ff.js     NaN
```

Or if there are better ideas I am open for suggestions. After I've reshaped it, it's gonna be converted into a JSON-format.

Comment: You want to find a more suitable representation? It will depend on what you'll be doing after, but maybe something "smarter" would be to do a dict of lists. In your example the output would be: `{'a':['aa.src', 'aa.xml'], 'b':...}`

Comment: yes, that would work. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Turning it into a json/dict**

Ok so probably not the most efficient solution but it works:

```
import pandas as pd

# Recreating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Folders':["aa; bb;", "cc", "dd; ee; ff;"], 'Files':['aa.src aa.xml ; bb.src bb.war ;', 'cc.pom cc.py cc.js ;', 'dd.ts dd.js ; ee.py ; ff.xml ff.js ;']})

#Split df according to ; and removing leading ;
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip(';').str.split(';'))
print(df)
```

So now your dataframe looks like this:

```
          Folders                                    Files
0       [aa,  bb]        [aa.src aa.xml ,  bb.src bb.war ]
1            [cc]                    [cc.pom cc.py cc.js ]
2  [dd,  ee,  ff]  [dd.ts dd.js ,  ee.py ,  ff.xml ff.js ]
```

Then I loop through the dataframe to build the dict:

```
# Creating the dict by looping through the dataframe and number of elements of folders
df_dict=dict()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for i, key in enumerate(row['Folders']):
    df_dict[key.strip()] = row['Files'][i].strip().split(' ')

print(df_dict)
```

And this is the output:

```
{'aa': ['aa.src', 'aa.xml'], 'bb': ['bb.src', 'bb.war'], 'cc'
: ['cc.pom', 'cc.py', 'cc.js'], 'dd': ['dd.ts', 'dd.js'], 'ee
': ['ee.py'], 'ff': ['ff.xml', 'ff.js']}
```

If you can encounter twice the same key, I suggest to use this version of the code who check if the key already exists:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Recreating the dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'Folders':["aa; bb;", "cc", "dd; ee; ff;", 'aa'], 'Files':['aa.src aa.xml ; bb.src bb.war ;', 'cc.pom cc.py cc.js ;', 'dd.ts dd.js ; ee.py ; ff.xml ff.js ;', 'aa.tst']})

#Split df according to ; and removing leading ;
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.rstrip(';').str.split(';'))
print(df)

df_dict=dict()
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for i, key in enumerate(row['Folders']):
    if key.strip() in df_dict:
      df_dict[key.strip()] += row['Files'][i].strip().split(' ')
    else: df_dict[key.strip()] = row['Files'][i].strip().split(' ')

print(df_dict)
```

Comment: A problem I'm having with the solutions is that, when for example folder "aa" appears a second time in the dataset, the files from the first iteration will be replaced with the second iteration. Is it possible to append, or add the new files into the already existing array?

Comment: I edited the code (see last chunck) with a version that would do this